# How to get specific value from string like in the query string

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net

I have  li with text `id=452/name=Vova/Price=457$`
i need in clien build var id,name,price and to each one get the right text that i can work with them 
This will look  will look like this

```
var id=452
var name=vova
var Price=457$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var liText = "id=452/name=Vova/Price=457$";

var vars = liText.split("/");
var obj = {};
vars.forEach(function(v) {
    var keyValue = v.split("=");
    obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
});
```

Access them using the object notation `obj["id"]` or assign them to your variables if that is what you want.

```
var id = obj["id"];
var name = obj["name"];
var price = obj["Price"];
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TZmED/)